# Microsoft Powertoys renders STL with color data on thumbnail, how can i bring it to blender?

Tags: rendering, color, shader-nodes, vertex-colors, stl

I have my STL files on the folder and powertoys are installed on my PC so i can review STL files.
I noticed that Powertoys are actually rendering color to them, which is odd as i thought STL files don't contain color data.

[image: Here's the proof of thumbnail, STL files with color, one without]

Is it possible to get that information in blender so i can have renders of them?
No need to be PBR, it's just the color information i'm interested in.

I thought these were vertex color data, when i imported the STL, go to shader editor and add Color Attribute to the shader, nothing shows up unfortunately.

[image: Here'^s with the Color attribute node imported]

It'll be awesome if someone can help me out, it's interesting to see colors in the powertoys thumbnails!

Comment: There is no mention of colour at all in Blender's [STL Export format](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/mesh_stl.html#exporting) so those files can't have been produced by blender.

Comment: Yeah that's not what i've actually meant. Ty for the efford though, figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

So here's what i did, maybe it'll be usefull for someone.
I've imported the STL to ZBrush. Clicked "with color" after importing (it automaticly pops out)
Then i've exported it as fbx, then imported into blender.
Added color attribute to principled bsdf base color.
And it had.

STL can carry color/vertex color data, but some how, it doesn't display it.
So i had to make that transition. I try to export stl as fbx in blender but it didn't preserved the data.